# Download files from server in web2py

Tags: python, web2py

I am currently setting up a website where I get a file uploaded from the user , do some processing on it and provide a link for the user to download the processed file from. I presently want to provide a path to the file on my local system, I am new to web2py, and am having trouble doing this.

Could someone please help me do this?

Regards

Comment: you should describe what trouble : the error message, which step are you in now? are you finish the upload ? save it to some path on server? or you have problem on downloading the processed file?

Comment: Thanks for the reply pinkdawn. Yes I have uploaded the file. it is in a certain folder on my system. I need to present a download link to this file in one of the views.

Answer (score 0):

see this link for some hint: [webpy: how to stream files](http://webpy.org/cookbook/streaming_large_files) , and may be add some code like this:

```
BUF_SIZE = 262144
class download:
    def GET(self):
        file_name = # get from url
        file_path = os.path.join('/path to your file', file_name)
        f = None
        try:
            f = open(file_path, "rb")
            webpy.header('Content-Type','application/octet-stream')
            webpy.header('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=%s' % file_name)
            while True:
                c = f.read(BUF_SIZE)
                if c:
                    yield c
                else:
                    break
        except Exception, e:
            # throw 403 or 500 or just leave it
            pass
        finally:
            if f:
                f.close()
```

Comment: I believe he is asking about web2py, not web.py.